# Where is the class instance created in this php Example?

Tags: php, class, authentication, instance

I'm quite new to PHP but used to some other programming languages (e.g JAVA,Python). Recently I had a closer look to the Login-Script panique/php-login-advanced (https://github.com/panique/php-login-advanced) which I find is a really good way to learn some useful PHP-structures.

Unfortunately there is one thing, i don't understand and which gives me quite a headache: all starts from "index.php" whih includes "login_manager.php" (used, among others, to create a new Login-instance from "classes/Login.php").

```
// create a login object. when this object is created, it will do all login/logout stuff automatically
// so this single line handles the entire login process.
$login = new Login();
```

If you aren't logged in, you can register yourself, which leads you to "views/register.php". In this file there is a POST-form, calling the same file again:

```
<?php include('_header.php'); ?>

<!-- show registration form, but only if we didn't submit already -->
<?php if (!$registration->registration_successful && !$registration->verification_successful) { ?>
<form method="post" action="register.php" name="registerform">
    <label for="user_name"><?php echo WORDING_REGISTRATION_USERNAME; ?></label>
    <input id="user_name" type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,64}" name="user_name" required />

    <label for="user_email"><?php echo WORDING_REGISTRATION_EMAIL; ?></label>
    <input id="user_email" type="email" name="user_email" required />

    <label for="user_password_new"><?php echo WORDING_REGISTRATION_PASSWORD; ?></label>
    <input id="user_password_new" type="password" name="user_password_new" pattern=".{6,}" required autocomplete="off" />

    <label for="user_password_repeat"><?php echo WORDING_REGISTRATION_PASSWORD_REPEAT; ?></label>
    <input id="user_password_repeat" type="password" name="user_password_repeat" pattern=".{6,}" required autocomplete="off" />

    <img src="tools/showCaptcha.php" alt="captcha" />

    <label><?php echo WORDING_REGISTRATION_CAPTCHA; ?></label>
    <input type="text" name="captcha" required />

    <input type="submit" name="register" value="<?php echo WORDING_REGISTER; ?>" />
</form>
<?php } ?>

    <a href="index.php"><?php echo WORDING_BACK_TO_LOGIN; ?></a>

<?php include('_footer.php'); ?>
```

Now I don't understand where this $registration instance comes from?! Of course it should be an instance of "classes/Registration.php" which explains the further processing using the constructor of the class:

```
public function __construct()
    {
        session_start();

        // if we have such a POST request, call the registerNewUser() method
        if (isset($_POST["register"])) {
            $this->registerNewUser($_POST['user_name'], $_POST['user_email'], $_POST['user_password_new'], $_POST['user_password_repeat'], $_POST["captcha"]);
        // if we have such a GET request, call the verifyNewUser() method
        } else if (isset($_GET["id"]) && isset($_GET["verification_code"])) {
            $this->verifyNewUser($_GET["id"], $_GET["verification_code"]);
        }
    }
```

But where is the connection here? I searched the complete project with all files and I could not find something like "new Registration()" and even the $registration variable is never set (to my knowledge). So as the script works without problems, there needs to be some trick i don't know.

I also thought it could be set in the "_header.php" but in this file there is only some error-output:

```
// show potential errors / feedback (from registration object)
if (isset($registration)) {
    if ($registration->errors) {
        foreach ($registration->errors as $error) {
            echo $error;
        }
    }
    if ($registration->messages) {
        foreach ($registration->messages as $message) {
            echo $message;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the `register.php` file in the root directory [https://github.com/panique/php-login-advanced/blob/master/register.php](https://github.com/panique/php-login-advanced/blob/master/register.php)

Comment: omg, thanks a lot!! I found my mistake: i syncronized my files using FTP with my webserver. Unfortunately this "register.php" in the root directory was missing on the local machine, but did exist on the webserver. This is why it worked, but i couldn't see why... Thanks again!